# Creating a view that returns distinct id with the latest date

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I'm trying to build a view that has contains user_id, date, and a statistics value, but I'm running into an issue.

Essentially if I have a table that contains:

```
ID  Stat  Date        
--------------------
01  AAA   01/01/2010
02  BBB   02/02/2010  
03  CCC   05/01/2010
03  DDD   06/01/2010
01  EEE   07/01/2010
```

My view should have:

```
ID  Stat  Date        
-------------------- 
02  BBB   02/02/2010 
03  DDD   06/01/2010
01  EEE   07/01/2010
```

I've looked around and I found that this query would work:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT * 
            FROM TABLE 
        ORDER BY DATE DESC) tmp 
GROUP BY ID
```

Now the problem is that it doesn't seem like I can do subqueries in views in MYSQL.

I've tried splitting it into two views, the first one like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VIEW_TEMP AS
  SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE 
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

and the second:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW NEW_VIEW AS
  SELECT * 
    FROM VIEW_TEMP 
GROUP BY ID
```

The problem is that while the first view returns the same results as the subquery, the second view gives me wrong date values.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.stat,
       a.date
  FROM YOUR_TABLE a
  JOIN (SELECT t.id,
               MAX(t.date) AS max_date
          FROM YOUR_TABLE t
      GROUP BY t.id) b ON b.id = a.id
                      AND b.max_date = a.date
```

I haven't tested this for creating a view, but I recall that MySQL didn't allow subqueries in views.  [According to the documentation, about view restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html):

> The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.

Additionally, there is the chance for duplicates if there's 2+ id values with identical max date values -- Add `DISTINCT` to the query if necessary.

The self join guarantees that the value returned for the stat column - [that can't be said if relying on MySQL's hidden column in the GROUP BY functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html):

```
  SELECT a.id, 
         a.stat,
         MAX(a.date) AS date
    FROM YOUR_TABLE a
GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: Right. In plain english: get the max date for each id, then get the stat for that id and date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY id, date
HAVING MAX(date)
```